# In programming terms, what do you call this import behavior?

Tags: python

I have a file called "const_a.py"
it has this in it

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
```

Then I have another const file called "const_b.py"
it has this

```
from const_a import *

THREE = 3
FOUR = 4
```

Finally I am printing out some values in test.py

```
from const_b import *

print(ONE)
print(THREE)
```

That prints out 1 and 3. I would have expected it to error out trying to print `ONE`. Apparently `const_b` now has `const_a`  in it.

What is this behavior called? Is it intentional?

Comment: What do you think an import statement does?

Comment: What is confusing about this behavior?

Comment: It's called *importing*. In `const_by.py` you did `from const_a import *` which assigns everything in `const_a` to the same name in `const_b`'s global namespace

Comment: You've imported all names from `const_a` into `const_b` and then all names from `const_b` into `__main__`, so there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Oh importing! DUH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from const_a import *` is effectively equivalent to

```
import const_a
ONE = const_a.ONE
TWO = const_a.TWO
del const_a
```

You are creating names in `const_b` whose values are taken from the identically named variables in `const_a`.

Comment: Fixed, I think :)